# ipv6 number of Host Address

Tags: ip, ipv6, ip-address

I'm trying to find the number of host addresses of IPv6, I know the correct answer is 18.4 × 10<sup>18</sup>

I cannot seem to correctly calculate the formula to reach the correct answer, please help me.

IPv6 = 16 bytes long, 16 bytes (16 × 8 = 128) = 128 bits, number of IPv6 addresses = 2<sup>128</sup> = 3.402823669 × 10<sup>38</sup>.
Equal parts of 64 bits each for network and host (64 + 64 = 128), 2<sup>64</sup> = 1.844674407 × 10<sup>19</sup>

Comment: 1.84x10^19 is the same as 18.4x10^18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like with IPv4, you subtract the mask length from the size of the address (32 for IPv4, and 128 for IPv6) to get the number of host bits. Take two to the power of the number of host bits, and that is how many host addresses you have. With IPv4, you must subtract two from that number (except for `/31` and `/32` networks) because you cannot use the network or broadcast addresses. With IPv6, you can actually use any address in the hosts addresses.

The standard IPv6 network size is `/64`, so you will have `128 - 64 = 64` host bits, and that is `2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616` host addresses in a standard 64-bit IPv6 network.

Comment: Just as a small, additional resource, to get the actual number when calculating IPv6, I started using the [Online Big Number Calculator](https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm).